# How to refer multiple model object using one model field in django?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

Suppose, I have **Project** and **Manager** model.

```
 class Project(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

 class Manager(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     role = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     projects = This would be array of Project object. But how can I 
                implement this?
     class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'role')
```

Manager with different name and role can have same projects.

PostgreSQL has ArrayField for this implementation. But I want a solution that will work for any database. Any alternative solution would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

In Django, you can define a Many to One relationship using the ForeignKey model field, then, the framework will create a reverse relationship automatically for you.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    manager = models.ForeignKey('Manager', related_name='projects')

class Manager(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Now your API can be used as this:

```
my_manager = Manager(name='Hasanul')
project_one = Project(name='foo', manager=my_manager)
project_two = Project(name='bar', manager=my_manager)

# you can use the reverse relationship (defined with a related name).
# note that it won't return an Array, it's a QuerySet object, that
# behaves like an array.
my_manager.projects.all() # [Project<name: 'foo'>, Project<name: 'bar'>]

# or the direct one:
project_one.manager # Manager<name: 'Hasanul'>
```

Please note that we defined the `ForeignKey` in the Many side, in this case, in the Project object.

Comment: your updates doesn't affect the semantics of my code, simply add your missing parameters here and there and you'll be alright

Answer (score 0):

You use a many-to-one relationship, which in Django would be done by defining a ForeignKey on Project pointing to Manager.

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is that a manager can manage multiple projects.  If your business logic allows a project to be have more than one manager, then the relationship between the project and the manager is [Many-To-Many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships). Otherwise, you have [Many-to-one relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships)